# Uploading and saving images in mvc 3 before post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, image, upload

I have a problem with images in my web app. let say I have a form where there are some text fields, dropdowns, upload ajax control for multiple image upload and button Save.

I know how to upload images and posting a form and saving everything to database but the problem is that I want to achieve the following user experience:

User can upload multiple images and browser after successful upload shows thumbnail (this I know how to do it)...the problem here is that I do not want to save images to db before button save is pressed. Is there any convinient how to save temporary images...I have tried temp table which after button is pressed, copies all images to image table but here is browser refresh problem that looses all the data and images stay in a temp table. Can you use a session for storing temporary images or any other way (I think session is not particulary good idea for such things.)

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to achieve that is to use the [HTML5 File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications/#Example%3a_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images) and display a thumbnail once the user selects a file to upload. You don't even need to waste bandwidth as everything happens on the client. Once the user submits the form, then the image will be uploaded to the server.

Another possibility is to use one of the gazillions of available AJAX upload controls such as Uploadify, Valums Ajax Upload, Uploadify, the jQuery form plugin, ... which will allow you to upload the file to the server using an AJAX request so that you can resize it there and return the resized image to the client that you could display the thumbnail on the client.

Comment: yes I am already using valums ajax control...the problem is that you have to save it to the server to show it...or is there any other way so that everything happens on the client before post (this is really cool concept)

Comment: I'll probably do image uploading directly with valums ajax control without post so there is no complication with that matter

Comment: tnx for the html5 api reference...i did not know you can do that